# Define $\langle,\rangle_{(x,y)} = dx\otimes dx + h(x)^2dy\otimes dy.$ Compute the Gaussian curvature of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with this metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

> Let $h$ be a $C^\infty$ function on $\mathbb{R}$. At each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ define $$\langle,\rangle_{(x,y)} = dx\otimes dx + h(x)^2dy\otimes dy.$$ Compute the Gaussian curvature of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with this metric.

The Gaussian curvature is given by $K=\Omega_2^1(e_1,e_2)$ in this case I think. In order to fin $K$ I need to find the connection 1-form $\omega_2^1$ and to find this I can use the first structural equation, but for that I need an orthonormal frame $(e_1,e_2)$ and a coframe $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$.

So given the metric how can I find an orthonormal frame with respect to it? If I set $e_1=a\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $e_2 = c\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + d\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, then $$\langle e_1,e_2\rangle_p=ac+h^2(x)bd= \delta_{12}$$ and $$\langle e_1,e_1\rangle_p=a^2+h^2(x)b^2=1, \langle e_2,e_2\rangle_p=c^2+h^2(x)d^2=1$$ given these how do I find the coefficients? The two latters suggest that $a=1, b=0$ and $c=1$ and $d=0$, but this wont satisfy the first equation since it's always $1$ then.

Comment: Renaming the variables, this is simply the metric induced on a surface of revolution, so you should get $K = -h''/h$; an orthonormal frame is $e_1 = \partial_x$, $e_2 = \partial_y/h$ and the corresponding coframe is $\theta_1 = {\rm d}x$, $\theta_2 = h\,{\rm d}y$.

Comment: You don't even care about $e_1$ and $e_2$. Remember that the metric is given by $\theta^1\otimes\theta^1+\theta^2\otimes\theta^2$ when $\theta^1,\theta^2$ is an orthonormal coframe. Then use the structure equations to find $\omega^1_2$ and then $d\omega^1_2$ is immediate.

Comment: I’m not sure how you derived this. Is it not possible to derive the orthonormal frame from the given equations? @IvoTerek

Comment: The coordinate fields are already orthogonal (there are no mixed ${\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$ terms), so I just normalized them.

Comment: Do you mean $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$? I have a feeling that there is some relation with the metric to the coordinate fields you are mentioning that I’m not understanding. @IvoTerek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. It's not hard to see that the orthonormal frame you are looking for is given by $e_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $e_2=\frac{1}{h(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ (instead of trying to solve the equations think about how to force the conditions you want).

The dual frame $(\theta^1,\theta^2)$ is then given by $\theta^1=dx$ and $\theta^2=h(x)dy$. In this case the strucutral equations then relate these and the connection $1$-forms by
\begin{align*}
d\theta^1&=-\omega_2^1 \wedge \theta^2 \\
d\theta^2 &= \omega_2^1 \wedge \theta^1.
\end{align*}

On $\mathbb{R}^2$, the $1-$form $\omega_2^1$ is a linear combination of $dx$ and $dy$ so $\omega_{2}^1=adx + bdy$.

The first equation gives $0 = -(adx+bdy) \wedge h(x)dy = -ah(x)dx \wedge dy$ and since $h(x) > 0$, we have that $a = 0$.

The second equation gives that $h'(x)dy \wedge dz = (adx+bdy) \wedge dx = bdy \wedge dx = -bdx \wedge dy $ so $b = -h'(x)$ and $$\omega_2^1  = -h'(x)dy.$$

Now $\Omega_2^1 = d\omega_2^1 = -h''(x) dx \wedge dy$ and so $$K=\Omega_2^1(e_1,e_2)=-h''(x)dx \wedge dy\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{1}{h(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = -\frac{h''(x)}{h(x)}.$$